# Any way to hide comments in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Does anyone know if it would be possible to hide java comments in Eclipse? Is there any  trick I could try?

Answer (score 18):

You can fold most block `/* ... */` comments to a single line. You can't do that inside code blocks (method bodies, static blocks, etc.) and maybe a few other places. You also can't collapse multiple lines of `// ...` style comments.

You could always change the syntax highlighting colors so the comments are in the background color. ;)

To turn on folding: Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Folding

Answer (score 10):

Enabling 'Folding' in the preferences dialog lets you use the '+' and '-' buttons next to the line numbers to hide comments. Do do this...

Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Folding

Then the comments will go away!

Comment: It doesn't hide inline comments with //

Comment: In the top answer there is mentioned the '+' and '-' buttons.
In my case I need to use the:
1. 'Ctrl' + 'Plus-Numpad-Button' to uncollapse / show the Block-Comments
or
2. 'Ctrl' + 'Minus-Numpad-Button' to collapse / hide the Block-Comments.
=========
Additional note:
1. 'Ctrl' + 'Plus-Button' (NOT at Numpad) to increase Font-Size (like Zoom-In)
or
2. 'Ctrl' + 'Minus-Button' to decrease Font-Size (like Zoom-Out)