# How to hide comments and javadoc text in editor view?

Tags: eclipse

The reason i (sometimes) want to hide the javadoc text  is because in 3rd party apps it kinda confuses me. The fact that when i hover over an object  the javadoc for that object appears is enough for me
 Solutions?

LE I have just found somewhat of a workaround which is enough (a collapse all comments command). But for the sake of education, is there anyway to completely hide (collapsing isn't completely hiding you know) the javadocs and OR the comments ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346859/any-way-to-hide-comments-in-eclipse

Answer (score 16):

If you are using eclipse, you can "fold" comments by going to

Window->Preferences

And then in the tree, find:

Java->Editor->Folding

In there you can choose to Enable Folding, and then ensure that Comments and HeaderComments are checked for initally being folded.