# Can Eclipse join comment lines for Java multi-line (double-slash) comments?

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I configure Eclipse to join Java multi-line double-slash commented lines when I reformat? (Source -> Format or the keyboard shortcut.)

Example:

```
// This is
// a multi-line comment that
// I would like to line-join when reformatting.
```

It works if I use block comments (/* */) instead of line comments (//), but I like to use line comments in the middle of my method code.

I have line width set to 77 in the Formatter profile in the Comments tab.  I should note that it wraps // comments properly.  It just doesn't join them back after I modify them in the editor, which makes for comments that are no longer formatted properly after they're modified.  In fact if I add to a comment longer than 77 columns, it wraps the excess into the next line like it should (call it line 2), but then it doesn't join the next lines below that (call them lines 3 .. n) up back into line 2.  So line 2 ends up short.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to hide comments in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346859/any-way-to-hide-comments-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure eclipse to do that. Just add /* at the top and */ at the bottom.

```
/*
//
//
//
*/
```